# Force Jenkins to trigger separate builds for each branch event

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket "Post Webhooks" to trigger Jenkins Builds on every push. When Jenkins is busy and commits are pushed multiple times within a short timeframe, it may occur, however, that Jenkins combines multiple branch events into 1 build.

Jenkins receives all branch events reliable and even shows all branch events responsible for a build within the build info. E.g:

Build #10 (Jul 27, 2022, 1:40:00 PM).
Changes:

- 1.0.1 (details / bitbucketweb)
- 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT (details / bitbucketweb)

Events:

- Branch event at 1:30:00 PM on Jul 27, 2022
- Branch event at 1:35:00 PM on Jul 27, 2022

How may I prevent Jenkins from combining multiple events into 1 build and make him execute separate builds for each branch event instead?

Comment: Unrelated comment: I love how you referred to Jenkins as "him", you made me chuckle

Comment: @AaronMeese Haha, yeah I guess I thought of "him" as the butler in the Jenkins logo :)

Answer (score 3):

https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/

> You can solve this by making the one job parameterized. Resolve one of
> the parameters with something unique from the webhook. This will make
> each trigger unique and Jenkins will not batch the builds into one
> build.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set the quiet period to 0 on your pipelines.

> Quiet Period: Quiet Period is the number of seconds that this Jenkins
> instance should be should wait before triggering a Job. The quiet
> period is important because suppose your job is auto-scheduled to run
> at some particular time, or the job can be triggered as soon they take
> place.

You can also look into this link for more information : https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2010/08/11/quiet-period-feature/

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your response and the suggestion, but the quietPeriod is already set to 0, so this is not the issue. The problem only occurs when Jenkins is busy with other Jobs and therefore cannot immediately start the job.

Comment: You can always try to install the Priority Sorter plugin to assign job priorities and if you have sufficent resources, try increasing the number of executors or even add in other nodes to help reducing time between jobs.